# rimraf not found

Tags: shell, deployment, sh

I am trying to deploy a backend onto Render but i am geting erros below. And I also have a postgresql on Supabase.

```
Dec 31 02:26:57 PM  sh: 1: rimraf: not found
Dec 31 02:26:57 PM  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
Dec 31 02:26:57 PM  npm ERR! syscall spawn
Dec 31 02:26:57 PM  npm ERR! file sh
Dec 31 02:26:57 PM  npm ERR! errno ENOENT
Dec 31 02:26:57 PM  npm ERR! backend@1.0.0 build: `rimraf ./dist && npm run generate && tsc`
Dec 31 02:26:57 PM  npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
Dec 31 02:26:57 PM  npm ERR!
Dec 31 02:26:57 PM  npm ERR! Failed at the backend@1.0.0 build script.
Dec 31 02:26:57 PM  npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
Dec 31 02:26:57 PM  
Dec 31 02:26:57 PM  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

But as my package.json file below shows i have rimraf.

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start:dev": "nodemon src/index.ts --watch ./**/*.ts --exec ts-node src/index.ts",
    "build": "rimraf ./dist && npm run generate && tsc",
    "start": "node dist/index.js",
    "generate": "npm run generate:prisma",
    "generate:prisma": "prisma generate && prisma migrate deploy"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^4.7.1",
    "apollo-server": "^3.9.0",
    "graphql": "^16.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prisma": "^4.8.0",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  }
}
```

I tried deploying with postgresql is on Supabase and in env variables I have that url and production for graphql.

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  csrfPrevention: true,
  cache: 'bounded',
  plugins: [
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
      ? ApolloServerPluginLandingPageProductionDefault({ footer: false })
      : ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault({ footer: false }),
  ],
  context: ({ req }) => {
    return {
      ...req,
      prisma,
      // userId: req && req.headers.authorization ? getUserId(req) : null,
    };
  },
});

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(`server is on ${url}・・・`);
});
```

Comment: Check the docs for rimraf - odds are it's not installed correctly. It's not available to your shell. Postgres/supabase are not relevant to your question.

Comment: Maybe Render does not install dev dependencies. Also: When deploying to a service like Render - you do not need rimraf or anything, that cleans up the build  directory.

Answer (score 1):

it is resoleved. It was because of variables set to "production".

Comment: Which variables were set to production?

Comment: NODE_ENV was set to production